# Run a RegEx replace on a RegEx in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, dynamic

**I have the regex:**

```
var reValid = /^\s*(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|[^,'\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'\s\\]+)*)\s*(?:,\s*(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|[^,'\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'\s\\]+)*)\s*)*$/;
```

Which validates a CSV file, but I want to be able to modify the delimiter (') with any delimiter.

Is it possible to run a regex replace on a regex?

**Example - use a backtick (`) as the delimiter:**

```
var reValid = /^\s*(?:`[^`\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^`\\]*)*`|[^,`\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,`\s\\]+)*)\s*(?:,\s*(?:`[^`\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^`\\]*)*`|[^,`\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,`\s\\]+)*)\s*)*$/;
```

Comment: It is possible but could lead to unexpected behaviour... Build the regex using a variable for the delimiter and the RegExp object. That ensures only the positions that need the delimiter are affected.

Comment: @sg3s That's what I did, and it worked...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just use the source property to get the expression as a string, do your replacement, and then create a new RegExp object with the new expression:

```
var reValid = /^\s*(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|[^,'\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'\s\\]+)*)\s*(?:,\s*(?:'[^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*'|[^,'\s\\]*(?:\s+[^,'\s\\]+)*)\s*)*$/;
reValid = RegExp(reValid.source.replace(/'/g, '`'));
```

Comment: One issue, if the original regex has modifiers /[regex]/g you need to re-add them. It doesn't apply to the example I posted.